# What does "CON LAY" mean when it comes to conductor stranding?

Tags: power-engineering, distribution-network

I am reading the book "Distribution System Modelling" by Kersting, and in the Appendix there is a Conductor data. Under stranding it says CON LAY for some conductors (like 250,000 AA). What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Con lay" most likely refers to "concentric lay". The [Aluminum Electrical Conductor Handbook](https://www.aluminum.org/aluminum-electrical-conductor-handbook) defines it thusly:

> Most bare power conductors are in concentric-lay stranded form; that is, a single straight core wire is surrounded by one or more helically curved wires. The direction of twist of lay is usually reversed in adjacent layers. All wires of a given layer generally are of same diameter. The direction of lay is either right- or left-hand depending on whether the top wire of the helix extends to right or left as the conductor is viewed axially in the direction away from the observer. The length of lay is the axial length parallel to the center line of the assembled conductor of one turn of the helix of a single wire. Bare aluminum conductors conventionally have a right-hand lay on outside layer.
>
> American practice (ASTM) recognizes two classes of bare concentric-lay stranded conductors, AA and A, the former usually for bare-wire overhead applications and the latter for covered overhead lines.

Cross-referencing the parameters in the appendix for the example conductor you referred to (250kcmil AAC) against the [Southwire AAC specification document](https://overheadtransmission.southwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/aac.pdf) and the [Aluminum Electrical Conductor Handbook](https://www.aluminum.org/aluminum-electrical-conductor-handbook), I infer that the parameters are for Class AA stranded all-aluminum conductor, code name "Sneezewort". The resistance given in the appendix matches the 60 Hz AC resistance at 50°C.

In my opinion, the ambiguity and inconsistency in the stranding description in these rows in the appendix, along with the lack of detail with the conductor "resistance" (which should be specified as AC or DC and at what temperature--ideally at at least two temperatures so you can interpolate) make this appendix table mainly useful for the examples in the book but not so useful for real-world impedance calculations.

Answer (score 1):

In power transmission 99% I think they refer to "concentric stranding", i.e. the most common wire pattern seen for relatively low power.

Not an expert but it should affect power dissipation and some impedance characteristics.

Comment: What you say makes sense. I have scoured the internet for what it could mean.